# using JavaScript to write more JavaScript onto a page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a clone of jsbin or jsfiddle. I have written a javascript function which ammends code to the HTML when the run button is clicked. The HTML and CSS code updates and runs fine but I cannot seem to get the javascript to work. I am trying to get an `alert('hello world')` to pop up when I press the run button

## The following is the javascript code

```
document.getElementById("run").onclick=function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('updateable');
    var html= "<p>Hello World</p>";
    var css="<style>p {color:green;}</style>";
    var js="<script> alert('hello world') <\/script>";
    x.innerHTML=html + css +js;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7oskp4wa/2/

I have included my jsfiddle and hope it helps

Comment: FYI JSFiddle makes use of an IFrame, and run is simulated most probably by reloading the source.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an iframe? (Like jsfiddle). 
However what your trying to acomplish is doable. You can put all the script into a function and execute it when the html loades.